# Where are the dictionaries of Mac OS X's built in password assistant?

Tags: macos, mac, password, dictionary

Mac OS has a built in password generator. It is a little bit hidden behind the key icon in System Preferences / Accounts / Change password. The *memorable* option is quite nice as it even conjugates words (my screenshot shows the German version):

[image]

My question is: Where does this helper get its words and even variants of words? Is there a complex dictionary where it can look them up for the specific language?

Answer (score 1):

I've only used OSX in it's English settings. OSX has an inbuilt dictionary for system-wide spellcheck, definitions etc. I imagine it uses this for memorable passwords, with the Size slider determining the limit on the size of the words that are plucked from said dictionary.

Comment: That's true, but it contains only English words, no matter what system language you're running.